# FormMail and Email addresses

Tags: forms, methods

I have forms within my website like below. I've changed the domain names and email address as you can see. This is an example of someone subscribing to my newsletter and then receiving a thank you note afterwards. My forms all validate and work fine. Here's the problem... In the input field for recipient I need to include my actual email address so the form knows where to send the information. But of course, now it's exposed in the source code and can be scraped by robots. Is there a way I can have the form work but hide my email address from not only robots but actual people who look at my source code?

Thank you very much

```
    <form method="post" action="http://www.mydomainname.com/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" onSubmit="MM_validateForm('First Name','','R','Last Name','','R','Email Address','','RisEmail');return document.MM_returnValue">
    <p> 
    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="myemail@address.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Newsletter">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.mydomainname.com/thanks">
    <input type="hidden" name="realname" value="Website Request">
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

With some investigating and trial and error I was able to answer my own question, and hope it helps others.

In the FormMail itself located on my server I was able to add my email address to the recipient line within it. I did not know this option existed prior to me posting my question. My particular version of the FormMail allows me to do this, so I uploaded the new adjustment. After removing the recipient line information within the html in my page, I tested the form and everything works perfectly, and I received the form results in my email Inbox... cool...